# Finding the same numbers in an input and summing the paired numbers

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to find number pairs in an input, then sum up those pairs, but leave out unpaired numbers. By that I mean

```
8 8 8 = 16
8 8 8 8 8 = 32
```

so numbers with a pair of two will get counted but a number that doesn't have a pair won't get counted. Sorry if I worded this weird I don't know how to explain it, but the example will help.

For example:

```
8 3 4 4 5 9 9 5 2
```

Would output:

```
36
```

4+4+5+5+9+9 = 36

In Python.

Comment: You can try like a mergesort, but when the value is equal you skip them and sum up in a global variable... I think

Comment: Can you have more than two of a number? If so, how is it handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a correction of the answer @avinash-raj gave:

```
import collections
s = "8 3 4 4 5 9 9 5 2"
l = s.split()
print(sum([int(item) * 2 * (count // 2) for item, count in collections.Counter(l).items()]))
```

As explanation:

- we vacuum up all the numbers in to a `Counter`, which will tell us the number of times a key has been seen
- the expression `(count // 2)` is integer division, and gives us the number of complete pairs.  Thus if we've seen a key 9 times, `(count // 2)` -> `9 / 2` -> 4.

Comment: I get a runtime error   File "solution.py", line 5
    print(sum([int(item) * 2 * (count // 2) for item, count in collections.Counter(l).items()])
                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @bi0phaz3 There was a missing trailing bracket

Answer (score 3):

Use `collections.Counter`

```
>>> import collections
>>> s = "8 3 4 4 5 9 9 5 2"
>>> l = s.split()
>>> sum([int(item)*count for item, count in collections.Counter(l).items() if count > 1])
36
```

or

```
>>> s = "8 3 4 4 5 9 9 5 2"
>>> l = s.split()
>>> sum([int(item)*count for item, count in collections.Counter(l).items() if count%2 == 0])

36
```

Comment: I see how your solution works, but if there were more than a pair, for example 4, 4, 4, it would count 12 instead of just 8.

Comment: @avinash-raj Presumably its just strict pairs that should be added ... so if there were three 9's, the first two should be counted and the last not.  In that case the sum would be `sum([int(item)*2*count // 2 for item, count in collections.Counter(l).items()])`

Comment: @bi0phaz3 why it has to count 8?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Because I only want to count pairs, like 8 8 8 4 4 would count 24 because there is only one pair of 8 and one 8 is unpaired

Comment: In my opinion, the updated answer is still incorrect ... testing `count %2 == 0` means it will now not sum at all any number that appears an odd number of times.  Thus if `9` appears 5 times it will ignore all of them.

Comment: Thanks but if there is a tuplet, like 8 8 8, it will return 0

Comment: ya, think that's what you expected.. You didn't mention any of those in your question.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It should count 8 + 8 but leave the other 8. 8 8 8 would return 16. 8 8 8 8 8 would return 32. I mentioned "Leave out unpaired numbers" sorry if that was too vague

Comment: do mention all of those in your question i'm not a god to read your mind.